# CA1701 / Custom Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-analysis

In the `CustomDictionary.xml`, where / how do I put my entry to avoid these two warnings from VS2015 Code Analysis?

> Warning   CA1701  In resource 'xxx.yyy.Properties.Resources.resx',
>   referenced by name 'LoggerMustSpecifyFilename' the discrete term
>   'Filename' in string value 'Filename must be specified.' should be
>   expressed as a compound word. If 'Filename' refers to an API
>   identifier, case it as 'FileName', otherwise split it into two words
>   separated by a space.
>
> Warning   CA1701  In resource 'xxx.yyy.Properties.Resources.resx',
>   referenced by name 'LoggerInvalidFilename' the discrete term
>   'filename' in string value 'The specified filename '{0}' is invalid.'
>   should be expressed as a compound word. If 'filename' refers to an API
>   identifier, case it as 'fileName', otherwise split it into two words
>   separated by a space.

I don't want to suppress CA1701, nor do I want to change my string casing. I used the `CustomDictionary.xml` to block a few other warnings and those all work fine, just can't get rid of these last two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Code Analysis uses it's own CustomDictionary, located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop` or equivalent.

These can't be overridden with your own dictionary. There is a [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6772021-allow-overriding-built-in-code-analysis-dictionary) for this issue.

For **Filename** in particular, it's this that is causing your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Unrecognized>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->      
    </Unrecognized>
    <Recognized>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->
    </Recognized>
    <Deprecated>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->
    </Deprecated>
    <Compound>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->
      <Term CompoundAlternate="FileName">filename</Term>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->
    </Compound>
    <DiscreteExceptions>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->
    </DiscreteExceptions>
  </Words>
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <!-- .. snip .. -->
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

<sub>(I've snipped the items out of the default dictionary that aren't relevant, there is a lot more)</sub>

You can either:

1. Suppress the message
2. Change your casing to match this custom dictionary
3. Edit this default dictionary. This is particularly troublesome, as you would need to keep this in sync on all developer machines and on the build server.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this dictionary. I guess from various open source code I'm looking at people spell it FileName. Guess its time to change my code lol.